# Check if a value comes before another in a list

Tags: python, indexing

I would like to check whether a value comes before another in a list. I asked this question awhile back: [TypeError: 'GitHubIterator' object does not support indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38603449/typeerror-githubiterator-object-does-not-support-indexing), which allows me to access the last comment in a list.  I would like to expand this to look through all the comments in a pull request check whether `#hold-off` comment comes after the `#sign-off comment`.  I can print the comments using the print statement but, but it errors out looking at the order of the values with the error message: `AttributeError: 'IssueComment' object has no attribute 'index'`.

I think I need to somehow get the body of the comments to a list, and then use index to determine the order, because the iterator does not support indexing. But I've been unsuccessful in getting that to work.

```
hold_off_regex_search_string = re.compile(r"\B#hold-off\b", re.IGNORECASE)
sign_off_regex_search_string = re.compile(r"\B#sign-off\b", re.IGNORECASE)
for comments in list(GitAuth.repo.issue(prs.number).comments()):
    print (comments.body)
    if comments.index(hold_off_regex_search_string.search(comments.body)) > comments.index(sign_off_regex_search_string.search(comments.body)):
        print('True')
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do a `re.search(r'#hold-off[\w\s]+#signoff', comments.body)` which would return a match for your condition? I'm assuming that comments will be words separated with commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing yourself. The `for` loop is already iterating over the comments in order. All you need to do is test each comment for the `#hold-off` and `#sign-off` patterns and report on which one you see first.

```
hold_off_regex_search_string = re.compile(r"\B#hold-off\b", re.IGNORECASE)
sign_off_regex_search_string = re.compile(r"\B#sign-off\b", re.IGNORECASE)
special_comments = []
for comments in list(GitAuth.repo.issue(prs.number).comments()):
    if hold_off_regex_search_string.search(comments.body):
        special_comments.append('HOLD OFF')
    elif sign_off_regex_search_string.search(comments.body):
        special_comments.append('SIGN OFF')
if special_comments == ['HOLD OFF', 'SIGN OFF']:
    # add label
elif special_comments == ['SIGN OFF', 'HOLD OFF']:
    # remove label
elif special_comments == ['HOLD OFF']:
    # handle it
elif special_comments == ['SIGN OFF']:
    # handle it
elif special_comments == []:
    # handle it
else:
    # maybe multiple sign offs or hold offs?
```

Comment: I did come up with this solution, but I need to know which one comes first, because this will be expanded to perform actions for adding and removing labels based on the order of `#hold-off` and `#sign-off` in the list.  If `#hold-off` comes after `#sign-off` remove a label;  if `#sign-off` comes after `#hold-off` add a label.  In the example above, if both exists, it will always break on `#hold-off`...

Comment: I've edited the answer to keep track of the order that the two special comment types occur in.